# ngRoute navigation not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Below is my code ,written for ngRoute navigation

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);



app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/a1', {
    templateUrl: 'basic.html',
    controller: 'c1'
      });
}]);


app.controller('c1', function($scope) {
  $scope.hello = "BOOOO!";
});
```

Navigation is not happening to basic.html with this code.

I have tried solution in few links but thats not working.

My whole intention behind this is performing a parameterized navigation,like from first page I will be passing id and on the second page I will be displaying the data corresponding to that.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages in console?

Comment: no,thts the biggest worry,i get this while i click on the link too navigate http://127.0.0.1:55449/dmh.html#a1,no errors on console

Comment: do you have ng-view on the html ?

Comment: if i have that content on earlier page is also getting displyed,I need proper navigation